# PyEnv looking for virtualenvwrapper on system Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, django, pyenv

I have python `2.7.9` installed system wide.

Then I've installed `virtualenvwrapper` on that python version.

After that, I've installed `pyenv`, then I've installed python `3.3.1`

```
pyenv install 3.3.1
```

Hashed the shims of that version, exported `$PATH` variables of `pyenv` into my `bash_profile` file (I'm on Debian Wheezy).

Then, I need to run that python version `3.3.1` to work on a Django project.

BUT, I also need virtualenvwrapper installed on THAT python version, which is `3.3.1` not `2.7.9`

But when `3.3.1` activated, I try to run `pip install virtualenvwrapper` to install it on Python3, but it keeps looking for  the system wide version so I cannot install it, this is the entire traceback:

```
user@debian:~/python_examples/orthosie$ pyenv local
3.3.1
user@debian:~/python_examples/orthosie$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
You are using pip version 6.0.6, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
user@debian:~/python_examples/orthosie$
```

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe I can run it from system wide `virtualenvwrapper`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the python version globaly using pip, since it is invoked in one of the `/bin` dirs where you haven't changed your python version.

You can see where pip lies on your system using  `$ which pip`

To do so use `$ pyenv global 3.3.1`

When using virtualenv you can specify which version you want to use in combination with pyenv via the command:
`$ virtenv -p /path/to/pyenv/versions/3.3.1/python`
to ensure that you will get the right version - alternativly you can use the pyenv wrapper for virtualenv

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!